# Bootstrap form alignment issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to align two form elements side by side to create an hours per week field

e.g

Hours per week (box here) - (box here)

but when I use two col-md-2 with a  -  between them I get the result of

Hours per week (box here) (box here) -

Anyone have a solution to display the - between the two boxes? I've tried using 3 col-md-1 but the alignment gets all out of whack!

Comment: Show some code please.

Answer (score 2):

The below code follows Bootstrap form construction.  Using `.input-group` allows you to nest `.input-group-addon` between to fields with the `.form-control` class - though you do need to specify a width (hence the `.col-xs-9`).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="HoursPerWeek">Hours Per Week</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
   <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="BoxOne" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
    <input type="text" id="BoxTwo" class="form-control">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution without the bootstrap grid

```html
    <form class="inline">
      <div>
        <label for="HoursPerWeek">Hours Per Week</label>
        <input type="text" id="BoxOne">
        <label for="#">-</label>
        <input type="text" id="BoxTwo">
      </div>
    </form>
```

### Solution using the bootstrap grid

```html
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3" for="HoursPerWeek">Hours Per Week</label>
        <input class="col-md-3" type="text" id="BoxOne">
        <label class="col-md-3" for="#">-</label>
        <input class="col-md-3" type="text" id="BoxTwo">
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: In Bootstrap you should not combine `.form-group` and `.row` in this fashion, it pushes the boundaries too far on the left / right, especially on larger screens.  Also, what is the purpose of `<text>` in this example?  I am unfamiliar with this HTML tag.

Comment: I copied the "form-group row" class directly from an example on the bootstrap website. The <text> tag is from SVG and should be removed, my mistake. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: In Bootstrap 4 (currently alpha, not suitable for production) they have modified `.form-group` to function in this capacity.  In Bootstrap 3 it will cause the aforementioned alignment issues.